# Why is the my reference, which I created using `useRef`, producing this error message?

Tags: react-native, svg, use-ref

I created a reference like so for the animation on a circle svg:

```
const circleRef = useRef(null);
```

And in a `useEffect`, I have this line of code which is producing the error:

```
circleRef.current!.setNativeProps({
  strokeDashoffset,
});
```

This is the produced error message:

```
Property 'setNativeProps' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Seems like a typing error to me, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't know the type of the ref that will be held by `circleRef` since no type argument is given and the initial value is `null`. The inferred type is then `never`.

You can simply do:

```js
// Change `View` to whatever the type of component is.
const circleRef = useRef<View>(null);
```

I would also recommend to use the `?` operator instead of the `!` operator to prevent a crash if the ref ever happens to not be defined when this code runs:

```js
circleRef.current?.setNativeProps({ strokeDashoffset });
```

Comment: This still produces an error even with a type applied to the ref, as in `const progressRef = React.useRef<React.ComponentClass<CircleProps, any>>()` and CircleProps comes from `react-native-svg` in this case. The code works, but the Typescript compiler complains that setNativeProps isn't a thing, when it most certainly is as my app functions correctly. Just can't get rid of the error.

Comment: Only thing that I can do to "quiet" the TS compiler is set my ref to any, which feels wrong, but not as wrong as a red squiggly :) `const progressRef = React.useRef<any>()`. Your solution works if setting it on a View, but if you want to extend that to a shape, or custom SVG of some sort, not sure of how to type that Circle, let's say to extend the View so it's happy.